# Get custom field in SharePoint document item history

Tags: 2010

I need to retrieve the value of a custom field in a Document Library item's version history. The following returns a blank even though I know the 2.0 version of the document does have a value for the "Summary of Change" field.

The following code is not giving the results desired - sSummaryOfChange is returning a blank when there is most definitely a value for the previous version of the particular test document in question:

```
foreach (SPFileVersion version in spListItem.File.Versions)
{
    if (version.VersionLabel.Contains(".0"))
    {
         docs.Add(new Doc(spListItem.ID,ContentType.MyContentType, "Manual", "")
         {
             DateModified = version.Created,
             sVersion = version.VersionLabel,
             sSummaryOfChange = Convert.ToString(version.File.Item.Properties["Summary_x0020_of_x0020_Change"])
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to get it from the item's properties bag.
If its a column then use this:

```
sSummaryOfChange = Convert.ToString(version.File.Item["Summary_x0020_of_x0020_Change"]);
```

If it still returns nothing then try with SPListItemVersionCollection.

If you don't need the file's binaties but just the properties then no need to use file's versions. Use item's versions instead.

```
foreach (SPItemVersion version in spListItem.Versions)
{
    if (version.VersionLabel.Contains(".0"))
    {
       docs.Add(new Doc(spListItem.ID,ContentType.MyContentType, "Manual", "")
       {
         DateModified = version.Created,
         sVersion = version.VersionLabel,
         sSummaryOfChange = Convert.ToString(version.Item["Summary_x0020_of_x0020_Change"])
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SPListItemVersionCollection` instead of `SPFileVersionCollection` to get the custom field value. Example

```
SPListItemVersionCollection itemVersions = spListItem.Versions;
sSummaryOfChange = Convert.ToString(itemVersions["Summary_x0020_of_x0020_Change"]);
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to extract the code from my codeplex project [Export Version History](https://exportversionhistory.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NY.ExportVersionHistory/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Layouts/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx.cs). Hope this helps.

```
SPListItemVersionCollection itemVersions = listItem.Versions;
for (int i = 0; i < itemVersions.Count; i++)
{
    SPListItemVersion currentVersion = itemVersions[i];
    foreach (SPField field in currentVersion.Fields)
    {
        if (field.ShowInVersionHistory)
        {
            string fieldValue = GetFieldValue(field, currentVersion);
        }
    }
}

private string GetFieldValue(SPField field, SPListItemVersion version)
{
    string fieldValue = string.Empty;
    SPFieldType fieldType = field.Type;
    switch (fieldType)
    {
        case SPFieldType.Lookup:
            SPFieldLookup newField = (SPFieldLookup)field;
            fieldValue = newField.GetFieldValueAsText(version[field.StaticName]);
            break;
        case SPFieldType.User:
            SPFieldUser newUser = (SPFieldUser)field;
            fieldValue = newUser.GetFieldValueAsText(version[field.StaticName]);
            break;
        case SPFieldType.ModStat:
            SPFieldModStat modStat = (SPFieldModStat)field;
            fieldValue = modStat.GetFieldValueAsText(version[field.StaticName]);
            break;
        case SPFieldType.URL:
            SPFieldUrl urlField = (SPFieldUrl)field;
            fieldValue = urlField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(version[field.StaticName]);
            break;
        case SPFieldType.Invalid:

            // http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharepoint-spfieldtype-is-invalid-for.html
            if (field.TypeAsString.Equals("TaxonomyFieldType") || field.TypeAsString.Equals("TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti"))
            {
                TaxonomyField taxonomyField = field as TaxonomyField;
                fieldValue = taxonomyField.GetFieldValueAsText(version[field.StaticName]);
            }
            else
            {
                fieldValue = version[field.StaticName].ToString();
            }
            break;
        default:
            fieldValue = version[field.StaticName].ToString();
            break;
    }

    return fieldValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried using the following:
foreach (SPListItemVersion version in spListItem.Versions)

and

SummaryOfChange = Convert.ToString(version.ListItem["Summary_x0020_of_x0020_Change"])

..however it returns dupes. Could you please expand on your example above to illustrate looping through a document library and then outputting each documents version items?

Comment: See my update. Hope it helps.